# How to reuse index space that was not created

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

My database is 34Gb in size and I created a clustered index which I believe was not successfully created due to some error and I can't find the index anywhere. During running of creation of Index, i was monitoring the hard disk size and it was decreasing while the creation of index is running. It took 10 gb space. Now, after the error in creation of index, the 10 gb space did not return.  How can I get back this 10 gb of space?

Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: @marc_s How to move? Should I delete this post? I already raised this on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)